# Loading base64 encoded images with media queries

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I have a plenty of small images in my mobile web site. Therefore I load them base64 encoded in css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="max-resolution: 239dpi" href="small-images-base64.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="min-resolution: 240dpi" href="big-images-base64.css" />
```

The problem is that both small-images-base64.css and big-images-base64.css will be loaded anyway. Is there any way to load only the data i really need?

Answer (score 0):

the CSS will always be loaded  as long you link them.

One solution would be to make more css files and load only the ones you need depending on the page.

Another could be if you take the images out of the CSS and load the in the html directly just like...

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,AAAAAAAA........"/>
```

Comment: I cannot make more css because I have only one page :(
To load images in html directly I must know on the server what resources I need, which I would like to avoid. I would like to load different resources only relying on client.

Comment: as I said before the CSS will be fully loaded always. If you want load different resources relying on client why don't you put out all the resources which are not common to all clients out in different img files?

Comment: Because there are for example 100 different very small images and there will be 100 requests to the server. Therefore those images are inlines with base64 into css.

Comment: It's not possible, you must know on the server what the client wants an generate a custom made base64 css or, an html with the images in base64. That's the only way to reduce the size and the amount of requests. The browsers (client) will always download all the resources linked, whether they are displayed or not it's a different matter.